# Postgresql alias for mathematical equation

Tags: postgresql

like this

```
SELECT
  brand,
  SUM(unicom.amount_total) AS sale,
  COUNT(sale_order.name) AS qty,
  SUM(sale_order.amount_total)*0.15 + COUNT(sale_order_line.name)*65 + (SUM(sale_order.amount_total)*0.15 + COUNT(sale_order_line.name)*65)*0.14
FROM
  sale_order,
  unicommerce
  ......
```

I want to reduce the complexity in reading queries like above.
Is there any way to use aliases sale and qty in select itself?

I am using version 9.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot reference SELECT fields in the same SELECT-List via their aliases. You can, however, reference the aliases in an outer query, like this:

```
SELECT 
    brand,
    sale,
    qty,
    sale*0.15 + qty*65 + (sale*0.15 + qty*65)*0.14  
FROM (
    SELECT
      brand,
      SUM(unicom.amount_total) AS sale,
      COUNT(sale_order.name) AS qty,
    FROM
      sale_order,
      unicommerce
      ......
);
```

You can also use the aliases in ORDER BY clauses (but not WHERE, ORDER BY or HAVING).

See: [select-lists](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html) in the manual.

Comment: There may be performance consequences to doing so, though... I'd check the `EXPLAIN` to make sure there's not a second scan being done.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use your initial query as subquery:

```
select 
    sale
  , qty
  , sum
from 
(
SELECT
  brand,
  SUM(unicom.amount_total) AS sale,
  COUNT(sale_order.name) AS qty,
  SUM(sale_order.amount_total)*0.15 + COUNT(sale_order_line.name)*65 + (SUM(sale_order.amount_total)*0.15 + COUNT(sale_order_line.name)*65)*0.14
FROM
  sale_order,
  unicommerce
...) SUBQ
```

or create a view and query a view

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. But you can make the calculation less verbose by using table aliases and sub-queries, but that may incur a performance penalty:

```
SELECT
  brand,
  sum(u.amount_total) AS sale,
  s.qty,
  s.at15 + s.l_num + (s.at15 + s.l_num) * 0.14 AS big_sum
FROM (
  SELECT count(*) AS qty, sum(amount_total)*0.15 AS at15, l.num AS l_num 
  FROM sale_order so
  JOIN (
    SELECT sales_order, count(*) * 65 AS num
    FROM sale_order_line 
    GROUP BY sales_order) l ON l.sales_order = s.id
  GROUP BY name
  ) s
JOIN unicommerce u ON ......
```

In general, you perform every calculation at the lowest possible level - e.g. where you have access to all required columns, then assign an alias and use that in higher-level queries.